# Array of structs with char* wont printf() the correct thing?

Tags: c

I am writing a history.c and history.h which manage the command history in a command prompt I am writing.

Everything seems to be stored fine, but when I call the print_history() function with the 'history' command it just returns the same string over and over.

```
$ hello
add_history[0] command.cmd_str=hello
[0] hello
$ this
add_history[1] command.cmd_str=this
[0] this
$ is
add_history[2] command.cmd_str=is
[0] is
$ my
add_history[3] command.cmd_str=my
[0] my
$ prompt
add_history[4] command.cmd_str=prompt
[0] prompt


As you can see, above each cmd has made it to history.c with the right
string, but when this command is called it returns 'history' over and over.
$ history
    add_history[5] command.cmd_str=history
    [0] history
    [1] history
    [2] history
    [3] history
    [4] history
    [5] history
```

Here is the code for history.h and history.c:

```
#ifndef HISTORY_H
#define HISTORY_H

typedef struct cmd_struct{
    //void * pid; // not complete or correctly typed for this part of the project
    char* cmd_str; // malloc'd string containing the command that was run includ arguments
} cmd;

void init_history();
void add_history(cmd command);
void clear_history();
void print_history();

#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "history.h"

int buf_index;
cmd history_buf[100];

//make sure all buffers are initialized and ready to use
void init_history(){
    buf_index = 0;
}

//adds command cmd using a cmd struct and appends to the history buffer
void add_history(cmd command){
    history_buf[buf_index] = command;
    printf("add_history[%d] command.cmd_str=%s\n", buf_index, command.cmd_str);
    buf_index++;
}

//properly frees all memory and clears the history buffer
void clear_history(){
    buf_index=0;
}

//prints the history to the command line
void print_history(){
    int i = 0;
    while(i<buf_index){
        printf("[%d] %s\n" , i ,history_buf[i].cmd_str);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks liek C code. Why did you add the tag for an unrelated language? Don't spam tags!

Answer (score 0):

To be 100% sure we'd need to see how you are constructing cmd instances, but I can make an educated guess that it is using a common buffer so all `cmd`s have their `cmd_str` pointing to the same thing (i.e. you have multiple `cmd`s all pointing to the same C string).

Have you considered making `cmd` contain an array of chars instead of just a pointer?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm actually using ansi C, and I have tried changing cmd_str to an array instead of a pointer. The problem is it gives me an "error:flexible array in otherwise empty struct ->char cmd_str[]". Which I can't find a solution for. Also I think I need to use a pointer for this assignment.

Comment: Ok, if you are in C, then I'd have `char cmd_str[16]` inside the cmd (16 is a guess, you'll have to pick the size based on how big you expect the commands to be)

Comment: @John3136 If you're going to give advice like that (in your comment) to a beginner, you *really* need to explain what'll happen if the actual command doesn't fit in that buffer.  Ben: If you use a fixed size buffer, it is *critical* that you verify that anything you put into it will fit (or truncate it to make it fit).  Failing to do so will result in crashes if you're lucky, and giant security holes if you're not.

Comment: @Ray OP is still learning about pointers (the whole gist of the question), so I think that step 1 is use a big enough buffer and don't worry about the big bad world waiting to get you. Once you have the basics THEN add the extra complexities you are talking about. In short "Yes, you are right, but I don't thin kit matters YET."

Comment: @John3136 Even if we ignore buffer overflow exploits, he'll still need to worry about crashes if the input is too long.  Personally, I'd advise against learning bad habits that will need to be unlearned later (and the project he's asking about looks ideal for teaching these sorts of lessons, anyway), but at the very least, he needs to be aware that it *is* a bad habit so he knows to learn the correct way once he's comfortable with the basics.